# Fetch trending solana tokens without 3rd party API

Tags: spl-token, rpc, spl-token-program, jsonrpc-api, spl-associated-token-account

GM Buildooors!

What's the optimal approach to **fetching on-chain data about trending SPL tokens** like we have on platforms like Dextools, Birdeye, Step Finance etc.?

Preferably without the help of 3rd Party APIs.[image]

Any help would be appreciated, TIA!

Comment: Can you provide some more information about some criteria for what "trending" means? Is it number of transfers? Price according to certain dexes? Trading volume?